# Matlab for loop output into a vector

Tags: numerical-methods, matlab

this is where im at right now, the only thing i need is to be able to stop the procedure if error is below tolerance.

```
function [ z ] = dome(x,tol)
format short
n=length(x);
z = zeros(n, 2);
z(:,1) = x;
for i=3:n;
gprime=abs(x(i)-x(i-1))/abs(x(i-1)-x(i-2));
e=(abs(gprime)/(abs(gprime-1)))*abs(x(i)-x(i-1));
if e<tol break 
end
z(i,2)=e;
end
```

my output now is 
ans =

```
1.0000         0
1.5000         0
1.2870    0.1582
1.4025    0.1371
1.3455    0.0557
1.3752    0.0323
1.3601    0.0155
1.3678    0.0082
1.3639         0
1.3659         0
1.3649         0
1.3654         0
1.3651         0
1.3653         0
1.3652         0
1.3652         0
1.3652         0
1.3652         0
```

how can i make the program only show the table up to error tolerance level?

Comment: `b = zeros(n,1); for i = 1:n, b(i) = ...`

Comment: Change z(3:n,2) = abs(x(i)-x(i-1)) to z(i,2) = abs(x(i)-x(i-1)).  And put the next line outside the for loop.

Comment: YES! thank you!

Comment: It's better not to erase your previous question when you want to ask an additional or follow-up question.  That way other people will be able to read this in the future.  Also at the moment the code for your dome function doesn't seem to be showing up correctly.

Comment: You're right I just fixed it. Do you have any suggestions to make it show only the iterations up to the tolerance?

Comment: You could insert the line z = z(1:(i-1),:); after your for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
b = [0,0,abs(x(3:end) - x(2:end-1))];
out = [x',b'];
```

Edit: here's a version that uses a for loop.

```
n = length(x);
b = zeros(n,2);

for i = 3:n

    b(i,2) = abs(x(i) - x(i-1));

end

b(:,1) = x';
```

Comment: I need the for loop. I'm taking the difference here just as a simple example. I need to put the output from the for loop into a matrix

Comment: Ah.  For loops should be avoided in Matlab as much as possible, but if you can't vectorize your for loop then you can use martini's solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do it

> `function b = differences(x)
>
>   
>
>   n = length(x);
>   b = zeros(n, 2);
>
>   b(:, 1) = x;
>
>   b(3:n, 2) = abs(x(3:n) - x(2:n-1));`

If you want to use the forloop, you can replace `b(3:n, 2) = abs(x(3:n) - x(2:n-1));` by `for i = 3:n; b(i, 2) = abs(x(i) - x(i-1));`

Comment: I actually need the for loop for something else not just a simple difference. But is there a way to put the output from the loop into an array instead of it giving be b= b= b=  ect...

Comment: In martini's solution, $b$ is the array that you want.